# Linking multiple existing model instances to FactoryGirl object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

As a simplified view, I have the following models:

```
class LineItem
  belongs_to :service, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :line_item_template, optional: true
end

class LineItemTemplate
  belongs_to :service, polymorphic: true
  has_many :line_items
end

class ServiceOne
  has_many :line_items, as: :service
  has_many :line_item_templates, as: :service
  after_create :create_line_item_templates

  def create_line_item_templates
    # ...
  end
end

class ServiceTwo
  has_many :line_items, as: :service
  has_many :line_item_templates, as: :service
  after_create :create_line_item_templates

  def create_line_item_templates
    # ...
  end
end
```

So after either an instance of `ServiceOne` or `ServiceTwo` is created, the appropriate `line_item_templates` are created and linked to the service.

It's important to note that the `line_item_templates` association from `LineItem` is optional.

I'd like to create a factory that creates a `LineItem` which links to a newly created `ServiceOne` but also the `LineItemTemplate` that was created in the `ServiceOne#after_create` callback.

The pseudocode of what I'm trying to implement but haven't been able to get working is as follows:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :line_item
    service {|t| t.association :service_one}
    line_item_template_id self.services.first.line_item_templates.first.id
  end
end
```

How can I achieve that in a working factory?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there's a better way to do this, but the solution I came up with was as follows.

Using the `after(:build)` callback was essential for my various tests as it means regardless of using `FactoryGirl.build` or `FactoryGirl.create` it will

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :line_item do
    sequence(:description) {|n| "Line Item #{n}"}
    service {|t| t.association :service_one}
  end

  factory :service_one_line_item, parent: :line_item do
    after(:build) do |li|
      li.line_item_template_id = li.service.line_item_templates.first.id
    end
  end

  factory :service_two_line_item, parent: :line_item do
    after(:build) do |li|
      li.service = FactoryGirl.create(:service_two)
      li.line_item_template_id = li.service.line_item_templates.first.id
    end
  end
end
```